# How do I append double quotes("") using excel power query?

Tags: excel, powerquery

Using Excel power query im trying to combine a couple of columns into a string and one of the fields should have quotes around it. I cannot figure out the syntax to do this.

**Example below**

```
" '"" & [Column 1] & " " & [Column 2] & " as " & [Column 3]
```

Desired result

```
"Column 1" Column 2 as Column 3
```

Instead i get an invalid literal error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`""""&[Col 1]&""""&" "&[Col 2]&" as "&[Col 3]`

You need four quotation marks in this case.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking i had to use a single quote to escape the double quotes